# Distortion in format of data in Wordpad file when shifted from Windows XP to Windows 2007

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, wordpad

I have many data files which were set to open in Wordpad in Windows XP. Those files have a particular format for data, like following:

```
Name of Data file
No. of data columns
Name of data in column_1
Name of data in column_2
.
.
.
Name of data in column_n
column_1 column_2 column_3 ... column_n
```

Now my computer has been formatted and the OS has been changed to Windows 2007, however when I open my data files in Wordpad the above format of data is no more present. The format in Wordpad in Windows 2007 seems to be distorted. Does anyone knows what to do to restore the format as shown above, which is what the data used to look like in XP?

I have attached the snapshot of the new distorted format of data as seen in Wordpad in Windows 2007. The snapshot shows 100 column names, however the data columns present are only 5 when it should be actually 100 data columns.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on `View` then `Word Wrap` then `No Wrap`.

Comment: Wow! It helped. Thanks! Can you tell what happens with `wrap view`?

Comment: @Harpreet: If it's the one I'm thinking of, it wraps the edge of the window instead of the ruler margin. In your question, the image shows that your text is wrapping at the margins set in the ruler above the document and below the ribbon menu.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Word 2010, there is an option where you can try to open the file there where you have your selection of various formats. Try that and see if you can open it in its original form.